# Округление чисел

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! У меня вот такой вопрос. Как можно сделать, чтоб выводило на экран косинусы углов 45 и 40 градусов 0.707 и 0.766, а не все число.

```
public class MATH {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        final int a = 60;
        final int b = 45;
        final int c = 40;
        float a_60 = (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(a));
        float b_45 = (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(b)); 
        float c_40 = (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(c));
        System.out.println("Косинус 60 градусов = " + a_60);
        System.out.println("Косинус 45 градусов = " + b_45);
        System.out.println("Косинус 40 градусов = " + c_40);
    }
}
```

Выводит результат:

> Косинус 60 градусов = 0.5
>   Косинус 45 градусов = 0.70710677
>   Косинус 40 градусов = 0.76604444

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class JavaApplication2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int a = 60;
        final int b = 45;
        final int c = 40;

        double a_60 = new BigDecimal(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(a))).setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();
        double b_45 = new BigDecimal(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(b))).setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue(); 
        double c_40 = new BigDecimal(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(c))).setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();

        System.out.println("Косинус 60 градусов = " + a_60);
        System.out.println("Косинус 45 градусов = " + b_45);
        System.out.println("Косинус 40 градусов = " + c_40);

    }
}
```

[RoundingMode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html)

[BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Comment: System.out.printf("%.3f\n",value) - подходит для вывода, а если надо будет использовать округленное значение далее...

Comment: хочу спросить тут, что бы не плодить темы (пусть админы меня поймут). а как данное деяние сделать на PHP? или результат вычислений не показывать на экране, а ввести переменную со значением угла ( те же 40/45/60 ) посчитать, и потом опять приравнять к какой ни будь переменной?

Answer (score 8):

```
System.out.printf("%.3f\n",value);
```

Comment: Только в клиентской части GWT не поддерживается.

Answer (score 2):

Округлить дробную часть до заданной точности самому.