# Погрешности класса Math в Java

Tags: java, математика

Заметил что метод `sin()` класса `Math` даёт небольшую погрешность в ответе, к примеру `Math.sin(Math.toRadians(30))` выдаст 0.49999999999999994 вместо ожидаемых 0.5
Можно ли это как то исправить без округления?

Comment: Для того, чтобы вы смогли самостоятельно ответить на свой вопрос, вам нужно узнать каким образов в компьютере хранятся числа с плавающей запятой.

Comment: Нет, без округления не получится. `Math.toRadians(30)` чуть-чуть не попадает. `Math.asin(0.5)` попадёт точно. Но это вопрос везения. Тригонометрические функции слегка неточные (жаль, но это неизбежно за ту цену что мы платим за компьютер).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы *гарантированно* получить желаемый идеальный результат тригонометрической функции "без округления", следует использовать собственную именованную константу / табличное значение:

```java
public static final double SIN_30_DEG = 0.5;
```

Также сработает *понижение* точности при приведении результата к типу `float`, но это уже можно рассматривать как округление за счёт потери точности:

```java
double sin30 = (float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(30));
System.out.println(sin30); // -> 0.5
```

Другие варианты в той или иной мере будут использовать округление в виде `Math.round` или [преобразований через `BigDecimal`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/25711/):

```java
double sin30round = Math.round(2 * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(30))) / 2.0;
double sin30bd = new BigDecimal(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(30))).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();
```

Answer (score -1):

Результат вычисления синуса представлен в виде двоичной дроби, которая может не точно представлять десятичное число. Используйте `Math.round()` для округления результата:

```
double value = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(30));
int precision = 2;
value = Math.round(value * Math.pow(10, precision)) / Math.pow(10, precision);
```

Можете использовать статический метод `sin()` из класса `java.lang.Math`, он который принимает аргумент в радианах, ведь их использование может избежать погрешности, связанной с преобразованием градусов в радианы.

```
double value = Math.sin(Math.PI / 6);
```

или вот так

```
double value = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(30));
```

в крайнем случае можно использовать таблицу синусов, если вы знаете заранее какие значения нужно будет использовать

```
double value;
int degree = 30;

if (degree == 30) {
    value = 0.5;
} else if (degree == 45) {
    value = 0.7071067811865475;
} else if (degree == 60) {
    value = 0.8660254037844386;
}
```

Сложный способ - расчёт синусов используя ряд Тейлора:

```
sin(x) = x - (x^3)/3! + (x^5)/5! - (x^7)/7! + ...
```

Пример кода для расчета синуса числа x в радианах с заданной точностью eps:

```
public static double calculateSinTaylor(double x, double eps) {
    double sin_x = x;
    double numerator = x;
    double denominator = 1;
    int i = 1;
    int sign = -1;
    double prev_sin_x = 0;

    while (Math.abs(sin_x - prev_sin_x) > eps) {
        prev_sin_x = sin_x;
        numerator = numerator * x * x;
        denominator = denominator * (i + 1) * (i + 2);
        sin_x = sin_x + sign * (numerator / denominator);
        i += 2;
        sign = -sign;
    }

    return sin_x;
}
```

Comment: `Сложный способ - расчёт синусов используя ряд Тейлора`. И какое у этого способа преимущество перед `Math.sin` кроме того, что он сложный? Чему должен быть равен `eps`, чтобы вызов `calculateSinTaylor(PI / 6, eps)` вернул `0.5`?